# unique value from xml file

Tags: xml

I have the following xml file:

```
<contract>
    <ID>4</ID>
    <name>Name of contract</name>
    <commoditycode>CS,CP</commoditycode>
</contract>
```

I want to have the comma separated values in "commoditycode" in a dropdown list like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="CS" Value="CS" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="CP" Value="CP" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

in order to filter my list of contract. Is this possible? Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  If you want to know how, try asking.

Comment: That is not possible. Computers are not that far advanced yet.

Answer (score 2):

You could definitely load the XML file into a XML Document:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load('your-xml-file-name.xml');
```

and then get the value of the commodity code node:

```
XmlNode nodeCommCode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/contract[ID='4']/commoditycode");

string commodityCodeValue = string.Empty;

if(nodeCommCode != null)
{
   commodityCodeValue = nodeCommCode.InnerText;
}
```

and then split that string into an arry of strings:

```
string[] elements = commodityCodeValue.Split(",");
```

and then add each of those elements to the ASP.NET drop down list:

```
foreach(string oneElement in elements)
{  
    ddlYourDropDown.Items.Add(oneElement);
}
```

That should do it :-)